# Trouble establishing JDBC connection to Amazon Redshift workgroup from Lambda function in VPC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I am facing an issue while trying to establish a JDBC connection to an Amazon Redshift workgroup from a Lambda function that is also deployed within the same VPC. My goal is to execute insert queries on the Redshift cluster using the JDBC connection. However, I am encountering the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The connection attempt failed.
at com.amazon.redshift.util.RedshiftException.getSQLException(RedshiftException.java:56)
at com.amazon.redshift.Driver.connect(Driver.java:326)
```

Here's some context on my setup:

I have created a Redshift workgroup and a corresponding cluster within the same VPC. The Lambda function and the Redshift cluster are both in the same VPC. I am using the appropriate JDBC URL with the IAM authentication method: `jdbc:redshift:iam://<cluster-endpoint>:<port>/<database-name>`
.
I have already verified the following:

- The Lambda function has the necessary IAM permissions to access the Redshift cluster.
- The Lambda function is assigned a role that allows VPC access.
- The security group settings for both the Lambda function and the Redshift cluster allow necessary inbound and outbound traffic.

Despite this verification, I am unable to establish the JDBC connection successfully. Are there any additional steps or considerations that I might be missing to resolve this issue? I appreciate any insights or suggestions to help me troubleshoot and resolve this problem.

Comment: Is that the full exception stacktrace?

Comment: Any luck to find out the solution ? Exactly facing same scenario and getting same exception